# Nested management commands in Django

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py, django-management-command

Is there anyway to create nested management commands in Django, similar to what the `docker` and `kubectl` have? For example, let's say I need to have the following structure:

```
|-->manage.py
    |-->restaurant
        |-->list
        |-->get
    |-->employee
        |-->list
        |-->get
        |-->delete
```

The following commands should all be possible:

```
./manage.py -h
./manage.py restaurant -h
./manage.py restaurant list
./manage.py employee list
./manage.py restaurant get ""
./manage.py employee delete tiffany
```

The argparse [subparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) looks promising but I feel like there should be an easier way using python modules in the `app/management/commands` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an argument for that.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('command_type', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        command_type = options['command_type']
        if command_type == 'list':
            # list command
            return
        elif command_type == 'get':
            # get command
            return
        raise CommandError('Invalid arguemnt for command_type')
```

**Usage:**

```
py manage.py my_command get
py manage.py my_command list
```

Answer (score 0):

[django-typer](https://github.com/bckohan/django-typer) does not separate the subcommands into different modules like in your example, but it does use the power of click/typer to make it super easy to define arbitrarily complex command trees:

```py
import typing as t

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from typer import Argument

from django_typer import TyperCommand, command


class Command(TyperCommand):
   """
   A command that defines subcommands.
   """

   @command()
   def create(
      self,
      name: t.Annotated[str, Argument(help=_("The name of the object to create."))],
   ):
      """
      Create an object.
      """

   @command()
   def delete(
      self, id: t.Annotated[int, Argument(help=_("The id of the object to delete."))]
   ):
      """
      Delete an object.
      """
```

Comment: I notice that you are an author / contributor of that package. Please note that you are [required to disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) if you post about your own projects / packages, etc.